# Check if a LI are overflown in overflow:hidden div

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, lazy-evaluation

I am strugling to make my own lazy load function on my own slider. The thing is I have a div container with overflow:hidden and inside this div a UL . Eveyrime I slide I want to load the image by switching from data-src to src the image URL. For that I will need to know if the LI is visible in the div container or not (overflown the div container). here is my html code.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:288px;overflow:hidden">
 <ul class="ui" style="width:3000px">
  <li><img class='lazy_1' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
  <li><img class='lazy_2' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
  <li><img class='lazy_4' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
  <li><img class='lazy_5' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
  <li><img class='lazy_6' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

So now if it loads I only want to load lazy_1 and lazy_2 because there are visible in the div . How can I do that with Jquery please ?

Thanks.

Comment: First show us what have you tried it so far.

Comment: "**my own** lazy load function" - so you want **us** to write *your own* lazy load function..? i dodn't get it...

Comment: No I want to know when an image is not visible in the div.wrapper for me after to make my lazy function.

Comment: how to if it is visible or not ?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle of my slider    http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/7/
All the images are loaded at once I only want to load the visible one for that I will need to know if they are visible or not

Answer (score 0):

here is the jsfiddle of my slider    http://jsfiddle.net/jdDYQ/7/
All the images are loaded at once I only want to load the visible one for that I will need to know if they are visible or not

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:288px;overflow:hidden">
 <ul class="ui" style="width:3000px">
 <li><img class='lazy_1' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_2' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_4' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_5' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
 <li><img class='lazy_6' src="image.png" alt="" class=""/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```